# Package.json and package-lock.json fail to sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

I'm trying to deploy 2 cloud functions to firebase.
When running `firebase deploy --only functions`
I get:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Missing: stripe@8.222.0 from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
```

I already tried running `npm ci` and `npm install` as prompted with no luck.
I even tried to remove the stripe module and reinstall it, but didn't worked.

I tried manually adding it into package-lock.json but didn't know how to do it and of course nothing changed.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?